# ajax POST return null on query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to send some data from JS to PHP and make a DB request, which goes back into my JS.
Problem is, I only get "null" as result. 
I checked and double checked my Query which is perfectly fine.
Here the JS:

```
var selectedEngin = getSelectedText(enginID);
selectedEngin = selectedEngin.slice(0, -1);
var roleNameList = new Array();
$.ajax({
     url: '/getRoleNames.php',
     type: "POST",
     dataType:'json',
     data: { engin : selectedEngin },
     success: function(data){
         console.info(data);
     }
});
```

And the PHP:

```
include_once ("config.php");

$userAnswer = $_POST['engin']; 
$row = array();

$query="select ROLE_NAME from type_vehicule_role WHERE TV_CODE 
='".$userAnswer."' ORDER BY ROLE_ID" ;
$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo json_encode($row);
```

If I give back "test" instead of `$row`, it works perfectly as well.

Hope you can help me! Thank you!

Have a nice day!

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: I think you need to loop through `$row` and push each row into an array and then return that array as the response.

Comment: If you are ORDERing BY then we have to assume your query returns more than one row. However you are only processing one row from the resultset?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes, I have watched it in the browser's developer tool and the result is "null". Yes, the jQuery library is included. As I said if $row is replaced by some text it works. No errors and I run it on my XAMPP.

Comment: Is there in fact a matching record in your database?  You don't check before trying to encode the returned row.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj, you mean like:
 `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
while ($row=@mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 array_push($enginRoles, $row[0]);
}
echo json_encode($row);`
Allready tryed .... same result

Comment: yes something like that. But you need to use `echo json_encode($enginRoles);` then.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I am sure that there are at least 5 rows, I think you suggest the same as Mohit B.?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj, yeah that is what I did, sorry forgot to change it in comment :P

Comment: Have you checked that the query actually returns records?

Comment: Yep, I logged my query (which came back to JS) and ran my query through my DB which gave me the response I was hoping for.

Comment: Does `config.php` assign `$dbc` to a valid MySQL DB connection? It's not declared in your sample code.

Comment: @BA_Webimax yes it does, it is declared in the config.php

Comment: What is the output of `echo $result->num_rows;`

Comment: The result is: "6", matches with the MYSQL response. Feel like we are getting closer?!

Comment: mysqli_result::fetch_fields  works as well

Comment: @M.Ebner Is your data in UTF8 format or a different encoding?

Comment: @BA_Webimax Found the problem. As you mentioned, it is some kind of encoding problem, but I do not really know where the problem is yet. The Database is in latin_general_cs, the data table is in utf8_general_ci. My php is in Cp1252. Great combo, good that the real server is not windows but linux! I try to find the right encoding for all and keep you guys posted with the full answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$dbc has to contain the info with the parameters to connect to the DB. In your case the $result is null as your connection cause an error.

Comment: connection works, $dbc is declared in include. Already checked it

Comment: try to change console.info on console.log. console.info is waiting for the object, and you send a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to get all of the data properly encoded prior to feeding it to the `json_encode()` call.

```
include_once ("config.php");

$userAnswer = $_POST['engin']; 
$row = array();

$query="select ROLE_NAME from type_vehicule_role WHERE TV_CODE 
='".$userAnswer."' ORDER BY ROLE_ID" ;
$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

// Walk the array and encode everything in UTF8
$utf8Row = array_map(utf8_encode, $row);
// JSONify the encoded array
echo json_encode($utf8Row);
```

Comment: works as well as `mysqli_set_charset($dbc,"utf8");` Thanks again!
Upvote (less than 15 reputation so not shown)...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to BA_Webimax I found the problem and got an answer:

The problem was the charset. I solved it using `mysqli_set_charset($dbc,"utf8");` in the PHP.

Thank you for your help guys! 
Have a nice day!